# Memory leak in 5.1.1

Tags: ram

I have recently got a new phone and I decided to root it. I have installed custom ROM ( CM 12.1 ). I am now experiencing quite severe memory leaks.
When I open YouTube it plays the video for 7 seconds and then it force closes due to OOM state. I even tried to raise the maximum RAM allocated to Youtube and that didnt help either. Does that have something to do with zRAM compression or OOM grouping ?

Thanks for you answers !

Comment: Have you asked other users of the ROM about memory leaks? I assume you got your ROM from one of the many XDA threads that cover CM ROMs. If you are using a nightly, this is more or less expected behavior as bugs are found and fixed in a daily manner. Better ask on the XDA thread about this, maybe the developer even answers you.

Comment: I actually asked that and no one doesn't have a clue about it.